# How do I flatten a dictionary in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, flatten

How can I flatten the below dictionary -

input:

```
dict = {
            "Key1" : "1",
            "Key2" : {
                "a" : "2",
                "b" : "3",
                "c" : {
                    "d" : "3",
                    "e" : {
                        "" : "1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

output:

```
{
            "Key1" : "1",
            "Key2.a" : "2",
            "Key2.b" : "3",
            "Key2.c.d" : "3",
            "Key2.c.e" : "1"
        }
```

The datatype of the input map is `map<string, void*>`
Output map expected is `map<string,string>`

Comment: Start by not using `void*`. You have no way of using the objects those pointers point at.

Comment: How can the type of the input map be `map<string, void*>` when the input is hierarchical? Post some C++ code please.

Comment: @HajoKirchhoff The `map` class template is not hierarchical. If she wants to define the input hierarchically, a "next pointer" is required. That can point to the data like at `"Key1"` or to the next node at `"Key2"`. There are better means in C++ to implement this though.

Comment: @harper: That's exactly my point. map is not hierarchical. How then can the datatype of the input map be a map<string, void*>?

Comment: The purpose of having void* is that it can either be a string or another map. This is how hierarchy can be created. I believe we can use the typeid operator to get the type. If it is a string then we just print it and if it is a map then use static_cast to cast the void* to that map and then call the same function recursively.
The question was actually asked in one of the hacker ranks for an interview. The function declaration could not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Use boost PropertyTree. The PropertyTree is able to represent a hierarchical structure and even comes with a small json parser. It also has std compliant iterators, so you can iterate over the tree and copy each node into the output map, effectively flattening the tree.

Something like this (taken from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/property_tree/tutorial.html):

```
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
ptree tree;

// read the hierarchical data into the tree
pt::read_json(filename, tree);

map<string, string> out;
flatten(tree, out);
```

Where `flatten` iterates over the tree recursively:

```
void flatten(const pt::tree &tree, map<string, string> &out)
{
   for (const auto &j:tree)
   {
      copy_to_out(j, out);
      if (is_tree(j))
         flatten(j, out);
   }
}
```